# PHP7 seems like xdebug is breaking but nothing in the debugger PhpStorm?

Tags: php, magento, phpstorm, xdebug

To enable `xdebug`.

I edit `sudo vim /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini` and uncomment the `zend_extension=xdebug.so` line.

I then restart `php7.0-fpm`

Here is my setup in PhpStorm:

[image: php 7 PhpStorm setup]

Here is the web server setup:

[image: php 7 PhpStorm web server setup]

I then start listening for connections

[image: PhpStorm start listening for xdebug connection]

Then mappings pop up:

[image: PhpStorm xdebug mappings]

And I accept.

Now when I reload the page with a breakpoint it does not break and the page just never loads. I then have to stop listening for connections.

After I do this the pc gets put under a lot of resource stress so I have to disable the `xdebug.so` extension again.

Anyone experience similar of have a solution?

I am on `Ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: Is it remote or local? Try to set Host in "Here is the web server setup:" as "shootingstuff.dev" and either uncheck path mappings for local debug, or define the "Absolute path on the server" for remote debug.

Comment: It is local. Unfortunately with the host as `shootingstuff.dev` and mappings off I am facing the same problem.

Comment: If I restart `php storm` it will break on the first line of code of `bin/magento`. Then when I process it does not break but the page will not load...

Comment: Is it PHP7 specific? Does it reach the breakpoint with php 5.x?

Comment: So how is `PHP | Servers` look now (after IDE helped you to create that new entry ... as original one was wrong)? Need more info. Collect xdebug log details (https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log) and share such info for such unsuccessful debug session.  You may also try increasing number of simultaneous debug connections -- maybe you have multiple requests (e.g. Ajax calls on a page etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map the top level directory or project directory and then all the sub files will automatically be mapped.

Remember to skip the `bin/magento` file.